# Hovering toast every 5 minutes

Tags: android, alarmmanager, toast

I've seen several examples on how to make some event to be repeated even when the app isnt running, but still I'm not sure if I got it.

With AlarmManager you can make your app to wake up to do something in some fixed interval without it consuming system resources between the periods, right?
But can it be to show up a toast over your current activity instead of having an Activity with a layout for it?

Comment: You are correct about AlarmManager, however, you don't need it as long as you use a service to show toast message over current activity using system overlay. I already apply this method in my app Volume Control Buttons Saver where I show a volume bar over any activity - let me know if you need any code

Comment: But a service in the background is constantly consuming resourse whilst the alarmmanager only consumes them when needed, I've been told to do it without the service, but I cant figure out if it's with a broadcast receiver or how, and how to write it :/

Comment: True - my service is running all the time - so no need for alarmmanager - I will provide alarmmanager code - It does extend broadcast receiver

Comment: I need it to be done the other way, but thank you so much anyway, I'll wait to see if someone can provide some help with the other method :)

Comment: I did post the alarmmanager way with repeating interval - just in case - thanks though

Comment: wait, but the broadcast receriver isnt a service right? I mean, its registered to device, and when the alarm fires it handles the system created intent and its done, except because of the fact that you're setting a repeated receiver so it doesnt dissapear after the first call, and it's not constantly running as services are. So it would be the answer I'm looking for, or I'm wrong?

Comment: You are correct. That is the answer you are looking for. You can set alarm to kick in any time you desire. Make sure you add   <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver> to AndroidManifest

Comment: thank you so much! sorry it took me a while to get it tho ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // this is where to start activity or service to launch toast message
         }

      }
```

In activity or boot receiver:

```
private static final int PERIOD = 60000; //or whatever you need for repeating alarm 

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);               
Intent alIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alIntent, 0);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, PERIOD, pi);
```

In AndroidManifest, add:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: why it was approved the edit of a guy who intentionally damaged the correct answer removing the manifest info?

Comment: @Dane411 - I reposted manifest info in my comment above if you noticed: Make sure you add <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver> to AndroidManifest - It was missed. I meant to re-add the info. I wondered why editor removed it. First time someone edits my response. Will try to edit answer again. Not sure if I can.

Comment: does 60000 equivalents to 1 minute or 5 minutes? thanks

Comment: @KairiSan 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute